# Why is the Euler characteristic of a planar graph 2 rather than 1?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, planar-graphs

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Euler%27s_formula), the Euler characteristic of planar graph is $2$. I'm confused about why this would be true, since for any simple polygon drawn with $n$ vertices we have $e=v=n$ and $f=1$, so $\chi=n-n+1=1$. And of course thinking of the Euler characteristic as a homotopy invariant, the Euler characteristic of a disc is $1$.

It almost seems as if when calculating the Euler characteristic of a planar graph they are counting the empty space around the graph as an additional face, as if that graph were drawn on the surface of a sphere instead of in the plane.

Is there a reason for this seemingly strange convention with ''planar'' graphs?

Comment: The are outside the polygon is another "face"

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what is the reason for counting the outside of the polygon as another face though? That would mean that planar graphs are imagined as being drawn on the surface of a sphere rather than in the plane. Since the Euler characteristic of the plane (or equivalently disc) is 1.

Comment: Yes, that's what people do.

Comment: So I guess they really ought to be called spherical graphs in that case.

Comment: It's unclear to me what this has to do with planar vs. spherical, except that in the spherical case you could choose which of the regions is "outside" the graph whereas on the plane we usually consider the infinite region as the "outside."

Comment: There is always area outside the graph drawn on an infinite plane. Otherwise you're suggesting the plane has a boundary around its entirety.

Comment: @Nij Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant so a closed (or open) disc of finite radius have the same Euler characteristic as an infinite plane. Compactness is not a homotopy invariant.

Comment: @DavidK Euler characteristic is a homotopy invariant, and the characteristic of a plane (or equivalently any disc) is 1 whereas the 2-sphere has Euler characteristic 2.